# Internal error occured during launch of waveform

Tags: redhawksdr

I am running redhawk 1.9 and am trying to lauch a waveform. I get the following error: An internal error occurred during: "Launching FM_Radio_Example".

```
org.jacorb.orb.ORB cannot be cast to com.sun.corba.se.spi.orb.ORB
```

The error panel shows the following:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jacorb.orb.ORB cannot be cast to com.sun.corba.se.spi.orb.ORB
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.TypeCodeImpl.copy(TypeCodeImpl.java:2017)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.TypeCodeImpl.copy(TypeCodeImpl.java:2054)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.TypeCodeImpl.copy(TypeCodeImpl.java:2222)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.TypeCodeImpl.copy(TypeCodeImpl.java:2234)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.AnyImpl.write_value(AnyImpl.java:608)
    at org.jacorb.orb.CDROutputStream.write_any(CDROutputStream.java:743)
    at CF.DataTypeHelper.write(DataTypeHelper.java:79)
    at CF.PropertiesHelper.write(PropertiesHelper.java:61)
    at CF._ResourceStub.configure(_ResourceStub.java:189)
    at gov.redhawk.model.sca.impl.ScaAbstractComponentImpl.configure(ScaAbstractComponentImpl.java:680)
    at gov.redhawk.ide.debug.internal.LocalApplicationFactory.configureComponent(LocalApplicationFactory.java:297)
    at gov.redhawk.ide.debug.internal.LocalApplicationFactory.configureComponents(LocalApplicationFactory.java:199)
    at gov.redhawk.ide.debug.internal.LocalApplicationFactory.create(LocalApplicationFactory.java:158)
    at gov.redhawk.ide.debug.internal.ui.LocalWaveformLaunchDelegate.launch(LocalWaveformLaunchDelegate.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:855)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:704)
    at gov.redhawk.ide.debug.ui.LaunchUtil$1.run(LaunchUtil.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

I have a device mananger node that when launched I get the following error. It may be related but I am not sure. The library in question is at /root/src/redhawk-src-1.9.0/redhawk/src/base/framework/.libs. I set the environment variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH to this path but that did not help.

```
INFO:DeviceManager - Starting Device Manager with /nodes/SI9138_Node/DeviceManager.dcd.xml
INFO:DeviceManager_impl - Connecting to Domain Manager REDHAWK_root/REDHAWK_root
INFO:DeviceManager_impl - Child process SI9138_1 (pid 24915) has exited with status 127
/var/redhawk/sdr/dev/devices/SI9138/cpp/SI9138: error while loading shared libraries: libossieidl.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
WARN:DeviceManager_impl - skipping exec param with null value
INFO:DeviceManager - Starting ORB!
INFO:SI9138_Node:GPP_1:Registering Device
INFO:DeviceManager_impl - Registering device GPP_1 on Device Manager SI9138_Node
INFO:DeviceManager_impl - Initializing device GPP_1 on Device Manager SI9138_Node
INFO:DeviceManager_impl - Registering device GPP_1 on Domain Manager
```

Here is the eclipse/java information:

```
eclipse.buildId=1.9.0.R201309261648
java.version=1.6.0_30
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of openjdk has caused some problems with jacorb.  Below are two ways to get around the problem:

1. Downgrade openjdk and openjdk-devel

   $ sudo yum downgrade java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel java-1.6.0-openjdk
2. Install REDHAWK 1.8.7+ or REDHAWK 1.10+ and launch the IDE at /usr/local/redhawk/ide/1.10/eclipse.